# C++ global char pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, char, global

Part of a larger program I am making requires a path to be read in from the command line and stored in a class. Because paths can be an arbitrary size and it's needed in multiple functions, I store it in a `char*` in the header file. But, for some reason, when I assign a value to it, the program segfaults.

The debugger (gdb) shows the following:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b4828a in std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*) ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

Here's the program I wrote to demonstrate the problem:

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

Test::Test() {
  filepath = NULL;
}

void Test::set_path(char* string) {
  char temp[strlen(string) + 1];
  strcpy(filepath, temp);
}

char * Test::get_path() {
  return filepath;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "Enter a file path: ";
  char *temp;
  std::cin >> temp;
  Test *temp2 = new Test();
  temp2->set_path(temp);
  std::cout << "Path: " << temp2->get_path() << std::endl;
}
```

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class Test {
private:
  char *filepath;

public:
  Test();
  void set_path(char *);
  char * get_path();
};

#endif // TEST_H
```

I'm not sure why it crashes. Is there something wrong with the method I'm doing this? Also, rather than just switching to `string`s, I'd like to find out more about this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "rather than just switching to `string`s, I'd like to find out more about this problem." Why, are you allergic to `string`s?

Comment: I did end up using `std::string`'. I just wanted to figure out why the `char *`'s didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`temp` (inside `main`) is uninitialized and not pointing to any valid allocated block of memory, therefore the line:

```
std::cin >> temp;
```

is causing input to be written into some unknown part of memory, causing undefined behaviour. You should either:

- Make `temp` a `char[]` and only read in an amount of characters that will fit in the buffer.
- Point `temp` to a valid buffer.
- **Better yet**, make `temp` an `std::string`, and let the `std::string` class worry about the memory management.

You're also going to be having a similar problem with `filePath` after you fix the above problem. `filePath` is being set to `NULL` in the `Test` constructor, and then you're copying `temp` to the block of memory pointed by `filePath` in `Test::set_path`:

```
strcpy(filepath, temp);
```

`NULL` refers to an address that you're not allowed to dereference. You should change all of your C-strings to `std::string`s and use the `std::string` member functions and overloaded operators to deal with strings in C++.

Comment: So the solution would be to make the `char`'s a fixed size (like FILENAME_MAX) or to use `std::string`?

Comment: @ChenXiao-Long: In C++, `std::string`.

Comment: Okay, I'll use `std::string`. Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

You call `strcpy` without allocating memory for the string to be copied in `set_path`. The manual page clearly states that `dest` must be large enough to contain the string in `src`. Besides you copy from an empty temporary. Although, your crash appears early, when you read from `cin` into an uninitialized pointer.

Use `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const std::string& s) : s_(s) {} ;
private:
  std::string s_;
};

int main()
{
  std::string f;
  std::cin >> f;
  std::cout << f << std::endl;
  Foo foo = Foo(f);
  return 0;
}
```

If you really preffer what you are doing:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(const char* s) {
    size_t size = strlen(s);
    s_ = new char[size + 1];
    // safer
    strncpy(s_, s, size + 1);
  } ;
private:
  char* s_;
};

int main()
{
  char buffer[1024];
  // be save
  buffer[1023] = '\0';
  Foo foo = Foo(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

The second example is still broken. It is missing a proper destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator. I'll leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'll probably stick with `std::string`, but I'll definitely take a look at your second method as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test::Test() {
  filepath = NULL;
}

void Test::set_path(char* string) {
  char temp[strlen(string) + 1];
  strcpy(filepath, temp);
}
```

I'm not sure what you thought that `strcpy` was going to do, but what it does is copy from `temp`, which is uninitialized, to `filepath`, which is NULL. So neither parameter makes any sense.